# Accessing Tor on Android device via a virtual wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking, android, tor

I've hosted a wifi network using a virtual router, with which the local area connection is sharing it's internet with. My Android device can connect to this wifi network and can access my laptop's internet.

Now comes in Tor. On my laptop, Tor can be accessed on 127.0.0.1 via a Socks5 protocol. I'm trying to connect to this network from my Android device. I figured that all I need to do is acccess my laptops localhost from my device. Since my phone is connected to the laptop's wifi network, I should be able to access localhost by using my laptop's ip address (192.168.xx.x). Unfortunately this does not work. Any idea why?

Is there a better way I can access the Tor running on my laptop from my device via Wifi or USB tethering?

Windows 7 (Ubuntu 12.04 is available if a solution demands it), rooted Android on CM9.

Edit: Orbot is not an option since it's unable to connect via the wifi's proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't support SOCKS proxies, only HTTP proxies (as of Ice Cream Sandwich). Point it at your HTTP proxy (Privoxy/Polipo) instead.

Comment: At the moment im just trying to open localhost on the phone's browser (http). That doesnt work. As for SOCKS, there are apps for rooted phones that can handle SOCKS proxies (ProxyDroid), but anyways, that comes in picture after I manage to connect to localhost.

Comment: Do you actually have a web server running on the laptop?

Comment: Tor runs on localhost.

Comment: Perhaps you should add the relevant details to your question, then.

Comment: I apologize, but running on localhost is not what i configured. Thats how Tor works.